# Signal en Django no se ejecuta dada cierta condición

Tags: django

Tengo un modelo `Evento` con un campo booleano `es_principal`. Estoy usando los signals de Django para enviar correos en dependencia de si ese campo viene en `True` o `False`.

Este es mi signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Evento)
def notificar_actividad_principal(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    evento = Evento.objects.get(pk=instance.id)
    if evento.es_principal:
        mensaje = 'Tiene la actividad '+evento.title+' planificada para la fecha '+ str(evento.start)
        enviar_correo_involucrados(evento, mensaje)
```

Cuando creo un evento por primera vez y `es_principal` es `True`, este signal no se activa. Si modifico dicho evento y `es_principal` es `True`, entonces el signal se activa y me notifica por correo. No sé porqué está pasando esto, tengo más signals en mi código y todos funcionan correctamente.

Tengo otro signal para `Evento` que se activa cuando el evento se modifica, este es el código:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Evento)
def notificar_actividad_modificada(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created == False:
        evento = Evento.objects.get(pk=instance.id)
        mensaje = 'La actividad '+evento.title+' ha sido modificada '
        enviar_correo_involucrados(evento, mensaje)
```

Lo pongo aquí porque no sé si estará afectando mi otro signal. ¿Alguna recomendación? ¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: Ethan, se me ocurre que lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar una sola señal `post_save` para tu modelo `Evento`. Mezcla ambas y crea una sola. Otra cosa que veo en tu primer signal es que no es necesario que hagas un query extra para obtener el evento en la BD porque ya lo tienes en la variable `instance`. Podrías hacer simplemente `if instance.es_principal:`.

Comment: @César no me funcionó. Uní ambos métodos en uno solo y sucede lo mismo. cuando inserto por primera vez un evento que es principal, no pasa nada; si modifico un evento principal me manda las dos notificaciones al correo (que se modificó y que se ha insertado una actividad principal).